# C++ Primer 5th Ed - Stanley : Can a base class with empty destructor making it virtual?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading the below excerpts from the above book (chapter 15 - Object Oriented Programming Section 15.7.1 Virtual Destructors).

> Destructors for base classes are an important exception to the rule of thumb that if a class needs a destructor, it also needs copy and assignment (§13.1.4, p. 504). A base class almost always needs a destructor, so that it can make the destructor virtual.
>
> **If a base class has an empty destructor in order to make it virtual**, then the fact that the class has a destructor does not indicate that the assignment operator or copy constructor is also needed.

I don't understand the part where it mentioned "if a base class has an empty destructor, so that I can make it virtual". I thought the only way to make it virtual on a base class is to have the keyword "virtual".

Any explanation be great!

Comment: The book means there's a virtual destructor that has an empty body.

Comment: `I thought the only way to make it virtual on a base class is to have the keyword "virtual".` But where do you put this keyword if there is no destructor declared?

Comment: From reading that statement, it sounds like one can make the destructor virtual by just having empty body (without virtual keyword). That's how i understand that statement "If a base class has an empty destructor in order to make it virtual .."

Comment: @yapkm01 Essentially the book is saying that it is often necessary to declare an empty virtual destructor in a base class, but the presence thereof does not indicate the need for other copy operations.

Comment: @Unmitigated This is also what confuses me. First it says a class having a destructor also needs copy & assignment. Then it says base class with virtual destructor wit empty body does not indicate it needs copy or assignment operation.

Comment: @yapkm01 It says usually having a destructor indicates that copy and assignment are required, but there is an exception for base classes.

Comment: The book is about C++11, why C++ 20 has been tagged?

Comment: @273K Correct. Just that i am running all my C++ exercises using C++20. Thought this case won't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 4):

The author here considers an empty `virtual` destructor to be a destructor that is still user-declared (not one that is implicitly-declared as `virtual` because of a base class destructor) and either defined with an empty body or defaulted:

```
virtual ~MyClass() = default;
```

or

```
virtual ~MyClass() {}
```

It is impossible to force an implicitly-declared destructor to be `virtual` (if there isn't already a base class with a `virtual` destructor) and so either of these are the only possibilities to make the destructor `virtual` but have it behave the same way that the implicitly-defined (non-`virtual`) one would. That's why the author says "*in order to make it `virtual`*".

---

The quote is saying that having either of these in a class doesn't indicate that the class *semantically* needs to define its own copy assignment operator or copy constructor. The destructor still does exactly the same as if it was implicitly-defined and so the implicitly-defined copy operations are likely to still be semantically correct.

A non-empty destructor, e.g. one that performs some non-trivial work with the class (not just something like simple logging etc.) is usually an indication that the implicitly defined copy operations will not be semantically correct for the intended behavior of the class, which is why there is the mentioned rule-of-three saying that in such situations copy operations should be manually defined as well to avoid the unintended semantics.

---

However, in connection with move semantics there is still a problem with an empty `virtual` destructor. Declaring *any* destructor in any way will inhibit implicit declaration of the move constructor and move assignment operator.

As a consequence, if your class has e.g. a `std::vector` member, it will become inefficient, since it can never be moved, only copied. Usually a class with `virtual` destructor is used polymorphically and not copied/moved around, but that is not always the case. So it may make sense to still explicitly default all move and copy operations (in line with the rule-of-five) in such a situation:

```
virtual ~MyClass() = default;
MyClass(const MyClass&) = default;
MyClass(MyClass&&) = default;
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = default;
MyClass& operator=(MyClass&&) = default;
```

Or (probably more likely), given that the class may be intended to only be used polymorphically, explicitly `delete` all of them to make it impossible for object slicing to occur unintentionally (see [C++ core guidelines C.67](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-copy-virtual)):

```
virtual ~MyClass() = default;
MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
MyClass(MyClass&&) = delete;
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;
MyClass& operator=(MyClass&&) = delete;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it means that, for a base class `Base`, you'd likely need a `virtual` destructor:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {} // note the empty body
};
```

This is so that deleting a descendant via base pointer calls the proper ctor and frees memory correctly. Note that copy/assignment is not needed here; at this point, we don't even know if the descendant class is expected to have data members or simply fulfills an interface without any data.

This is, however, only true if you're using naked and some of the smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<>`). When you use `std::shared_ptr<>`, your destructor is automatically saved so you don't need `virtual` destructors to keep a `std::shared_ptr<Descendant>` in a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` before destroying it.

Comment: I have skipped chapters and never covered much of copy control and memory. i went straight to OOP. So not sure yet what you're trying to say here.

Comment: @yapkm01 Don't. C++ is in some sense like math: if you skip `+` and `*`, you make yourself a hard time to digest quadratic equations later on.

Comment: yeah .. i was just bit impatient but end up scratching my head or knocking my brains out .. lol

Comment: @yapkm01 - By skipping ahead you might find that the book presents neat solutions to problems you just skipped. The reaction would then be "Why did they do that?" :-)

Comment: @BoP My bad! Just impatient. I guess in programming i have to learnt to be patient and learn slowly .. that's my weakness and being new to C++ which is one of the difficult language to learn (coming from C and Java background). Like Chapter 15 i can understand lots of it but of course there are certain area i am not familiar since i skipped those chapters.